# Export the "App_Code" Folder

Tags: kentico

I am trying to export my entire site including the "App_Code" folder which contains my site codes' folder, but the folder did not export. I read the Kentico document that I can export it as long as I checked the "Export site folders" option when selecting the export options, but it did not happen as I expected. When I check the "App_Code" folder on the target server after importing, I could see the site folder did not import.

I guess I probably miss some things, could you please help me?

Comment: check the package whether you have the file in the export, if the file is placed in a site code name folder under App_Code: \Data\Files\Site\App_Code\##SITENAME##\ or if the file is in the Global subfolder: Data\Files\Global\App_Code\Global\ and make sure you select the 'Import files' option and the sub-options to import site or global folders. Note that changes in the App_Code folder will make the app restart.

Answer (score 0):

Please check first your project type like Website Or Web Application from Source and Target locations.

1. If source and target is website then App_Code folder is available on target.
2. If source is website and target is web application then Old_App_Code folder is available on target.

Example :

- App_Code (or Old_App_Code if you installed Kentico as a web application)
- Global (exports with any site, if the Export global folders option is selected during the export process)
- (exports with the given site if the Export site folders option is selected during the export process)

Follow below steps:

1. You need to select Export global folders option while export then all files under the following folders will be added to the export package:
   ~/App_Code/Global/
   ~/CMSGlobalFiles/
   ~/CMSScripts/Custom/
2. You need to select Import global folders option while import then the import process includes global files originally exported from the following folders:
   ~/App_Code/Global/
   ~/CMSGlobalFiles/
   ~/CMSScripts/Custom/

Reference URLs -
https://docs.xperience.io/k12sp/deploying-websites/exporting-and-importing-sites/export-folder-structure

https://docs.xperience.io/k12sp/deploying-websites/exporting-and-importing-sites/exporting-sites

https://docs.xperience.io/k12sp/deploying-websites/exporting-and-importing-sites/importing-a-site-or-objects